# Node - How to write audio file

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, stream

I'm making an application that records what a user is saying, and saves it to a file. In order to get the sound from the microphone I'm using the [node-microphone](https://github.com/MexXxo/node-microphone) package. My application currently is able to get the sound from the microphone. However, when i try to write the stream to a audio file, and play it, i get the following error.

> Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not
>   support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to
>   compress the file.

Does anyone know how to write audio to a file in node?

```
var fs = require('fs');
const { Writable } = require('stream');
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output.wav');

const outStream = new Writable({
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log(chunk);
    writeStream.write(chunk);
    callback();
  }
});
let Mic = require('node-microphone');
let mic = new Mic();
let micStream = mic.startRecording();
micStream.pipe( outStream );

mic.on('info', (info) => {
    console.log('Info: ',info);
});
mic.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log('error:', error);
});
mic.on('stop', (stop) => {
    console.log('stop:', stop);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('stopped recording');
  mic.stopRecording();

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `node-microphone` documentation states :

> startRecording()
>
> Start the recording with the given sound options in the class. Creates
>   a new child process. **It will return the recording PCM Wave Stream as
>   Node Stream**.

I imagine your files are missing the correct headers.
One of the following modules might help you :

---

## [`node-wav`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-wav#writer)

> The Writer class accepts raw audio data written to it (only PCM audio data is currently supported), and outputs a WAV file with a valid WAVE header at the beginning specifying the formatting information of the audio stream.

---

## [`audiobuffer-to-wav`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiobuffer-to-wav)

```
 var toWav = require('audiobuffer-to-wav')
 var wav = toWav(buffer) // encode AudioBuffer to WAV
```